# Reinitializing initAutocomplete Google Maps API Places autocomplete upon dynamically-loaded HTML input text element target

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-places-api, google-places

On initial page load this script:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>`

along with the functions I've shared below are loading to support Google Maps autocomplete (JS) with Places library.

Autocomplete functionality works if the target input text element loads initially with the page; however, when I dynamically load it later (as part of a click event) (`$(element).html('<input type="text" id="location" />');`) the autocomplete doesn't work.

I've tried to reinitialize the initAutocomplete by calling the function again after loading the new "location" element (`initAutocomplete()`), but still not working. Is it possible to reinitialize `initAutocomplete()` for a dynamically generated autocomplete target (`<input type="text" id="location" />`)?

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };
```

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('location')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("lng").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
    }
}
```